# Flashing white screen when GPU is deployed for AI generation tasks

Tags: display, gpu

Ubuntu screen flashes white, sometimes partially, sometimes on the whole screen when GPU is used for processing generative AI workloads. It is very annoying and I have to logout and login again every time it happens.

What can be done to fix this?

## System Specs:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=2880x1800 visual=truecolor xres=2880 yres=1800
       resources: iomemory:800-7ff iomemory:820-81f irq:80 memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:8000000000-81ffffffff memory:8200000000-8201ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:c1080000-c10fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=2880,1800
       resources: iomemory:820-81f irq:45 memory:8210000000-821fffffff memory:c1200000-c13fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:c1700000-c177ffff
```

## Chassis Information

```
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Type: Notebook
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Legion Slim 5 14APH8
    Serial Number: PF4QVBXN
    Asset Tag: NO Asset Tag
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: Chassis SKU
```

Comment: Can you post some pictures? Which GPU is used for display? Are you using the right Nvidia version?

Comment: `prime-select` was set to `on-demand`.

Comment: I am using the default `nvidia-driver-535` proprietary and tested driver that comes with the ubuntu installation.

Comment: Tried tinkering with that before and it result in worse situations - the gnome desktop environment failed to load and I was stuck with the `tty` console. Had to reinstall to get everything up and running again.

Comment: You could try setting the Xorg.conf to only have the integrated AMD. Then you can use CUDA as if it was on a headless setup